# "connection refused" when my play app makes http call to itself

Tags: scala, http, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I am implementing a heartbeat endpoint/route using play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_45).  When
the heartbeat endpoint is called, I want the controller to make http calls to `localhost`.  If all of those
calls are ok, then the heartbeat endpoint will return an OK http response.

When I execute the following url from curl, I get the expected 200 response:
http://`localhost`:9000/oauth2/token.  I am also able to telnet to `localhost` 9000.

I am also able to use WS successfully with an external URL:

```
    WS.url("http://www.example.com").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").get()
```

However, when I execute it from within my play app, I get a 500 tcp_error response.

```
    WS.url("http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").get()
    WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth2/token").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").get()
    WS.url("http://HostName:9000/oauth2/token").withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").get()
```

Here is the exact error message I receive:

```
Network Error (tcp_error)

A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

Do I need to configure something to allow a play application to make calls to itself?  Is this a network problem on 
my box?  If so, why do curl and telnet work?  If a network issue, then it must be a jvm specific networking issue?
Could it be a security problem with play calling to itself?  Not sure where to go next.

Comment: I just tried it on an identical setup to yours (on a Mac) and got 200 OK every time. If I put a typo in my target URL I got a 404. I tried different firewall settings but never had a problem connecting to "myself". I'd look at your OS security settings, maybe try a WireShark trace to see what's happening?

Comment: Where do you trying to make this requests? In Global object at startup, in Akka, or in Controllers? Also +1 to @millhouse, try WireShark to see what happening.

Comment: I am making these requests from a Controller method which is exposed via my routes file.

Comment: @millhouse thanks for taking the trouble of reproducing in a similar environment.  That's encouraging it works for you.  Wireshark is a good idea.  I will also try getting a colleague see if they run into the problem.  Would be good to know if it's just me or something generic to my office/network/our sandbox setup.